# pygame.time.Clock() function not working on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: python, pygame, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu18.04. I have installed pygame module to play songs. But the `time.Clock()` function is not working. It is showing this following error after running the program: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Clock'`.

Here is the code:

```
def playSong(filename):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('/home/mjiabir/Music/rangamati songs/Roar.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    while mixer.music.get_busy:
        time.Clock.tick(10)
    mixer.music.stop()
```

Looks like Linux doesn't support this module. What should I do now?

Comment: `time` is referring to a function - either one that you defined, or that you imported from somewhere.  It is NOT referring to any pygame module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)`.

One way to look up modules of a package or sub-package is to use `dir()`. For example:

```py
# in a python interactive shell

import time
dir(time)
# output => ['CLOCK_BOOTTIME', 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC', 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW', 'CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID', 'CLOCK_REALTIME', 'CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID', '_STRUCT_TM_ITEMS', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'altzone', 'asctime', 'clock', 'clock_getres', 'clock_gettime', 'clock_gettime_ns', 'clock_settime', 'clock_settime_ns', 'ctime', 'daylight', 'get_clock_info', 'gmtime', 'localtime', 'mktime', 'monotonic', 'monotonic_ns', 'perf_counter', 'perf_counter_ns', 'process_time', 'process_time_ns', 'pthread_getcpuclockid', 'sleep', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'struct_time', 'thread_time', 'thread_time_ns', 'time', 'time_ns', 'timezone', 'tzname', 'tzset']

import pygame
dir(pygame.time)
# output => ['Clock', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'delay', 'get_ticks', 'set_timer', 'wait']
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use `pygame.time.Clock().tick()`, I would suggest constructing a `Clock` object, through `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and `clock.tick(10)`. Generally, it is good practice to utilize the object-oriented nature of Python, as opposed to calling construct methods directly.